# Nginx geoip environment variables Undefined

Tags: nginx, environment-variables, geoip

I've just try this documentation : https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-use-geoip-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-16.04/

Here's my environment :

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
$ uname -a
Linux diameter 4.11.0-14-generic #20~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 9 09:06:22 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

the nginx.conf :

```
$ cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf 

user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##


 geoip_country /etc/nginx/geoip/GeoIP.dat; # the country IP database
 geoip_city /etc/nginx/geoip/GeoLiteCity.dat; # the city IP database

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

The vhost conf :

```
$ cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/diameter.vhost  
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /home/david/*****/diameter;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name diameter.********
        fr.diameter.*******
        uk.diameter.*******
        us.diameter.*******;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

Fastcgi parameters :

```
$ cat /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params 


fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;

### SET GEOIP Variables ###
fastcgi_param GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE $geoip_country_code;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE3 $geoip_country_code3;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME $geoip_country_name;

fastcgi_param GEOIP_CITY_COUNTRY_CODE $geoip_city_country_code;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_CITY_COUNTRY_CODE3 $geoip_city_country_code3;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_CITY_COUNTRY_NAME $geoip_city_country_name;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_REGION $geoip_region;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_CITY $geoip_city;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_POSTAL_CODE $geoip_postal_code;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_CITY_CONTINENT_CODE $geoip_city_continent_code;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_LATITUDE $geoip_latitude;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_LONGITUDE $geoip_longitude;
```

And environment variables are undefined. Here's the log :

```
==> /var/log/nginx/error.log <==
2017/10/16 14:40:37 [error] 3533#3533: *5 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE in /home/david/******/diameter/index.php on line 2" while reading response header from upstream, client: 92.154.72.118, server: diameter.******, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "fr.diameter.**********"
```

I've certainly miss a point. I do not know which one actually.

thanks for your help,
David.

Comment: was this resolved? I had the similar question, can't get the correct value of country code , i have followed all steps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282599/nginx-geoip-module-undefined-country-code

Comment: @user1955934 sorry No, it wasn't. Since I've find a way with a wordpress plugin and a webservice.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you should use IPV6 databases of GeoIP, thay also work for IPV4 addresses.

Secondly, the Nginx GeoIP module is dynamic, so you need to enable it :

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-http-geoip.conf /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/
```

Last thing, in /etc/nginx/ there are two files, fastcgi_params and fastcgi.conf. If unsure, put the GeoIP variables in both.